# How to export multiple dictionaries with same keys, different values in txt file to csv

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of {n} dictionaries in a txt file. Each dictionary per line as illustrated below which i want exported in csv format with each key presented per column.

```
{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'}
{'a':'4','b':'5','c':'6'}
{'a':'7','b':'8','c':'9'}
{'a':'10','b':'11','c':'12'}
...
{'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}
```

i want csv output for {n} rows as below with index

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
... ... ... ...
n   x   y   z
```

Comment: What have you tried? The point of SO is not that people will come up with the code you need to do xyz.... the point is to help with specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x =[{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'},
{'a':'4','b':'5','c':'6'},
{'a':'7','b':'8','c':'9'},
{'a':'10','b':'11','c':'12'}]
n = len(x)
keys = list(x[0].keys())
newdict=dict()
for m in keys:
    newdict[m]=[]
    for i in range(n):
        newdict[m].append(x[i][m])
newdict
```

Output is

```
{'a': ['1', '4', '7', '10'],
 'b': ['2', '5', '8', '11'],
 'c': ['3', '6', '9', '12']}
```

---

Or you can use `pandas.concat` which is used to combine `DataFrames` with the same columns.

```
import pandas as pd
x =[{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'},
{'a':'4','b':'5','c':'6'},
{'a':'7','b':'8','c':'9'},
{'a':'10','b':'11','c':'12'}]

xpd=[]
for i in x:
    df=pd.DataFrame(i, index=[0])
    xpd.append(df) 
pd.concat(xpd, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: using pandas.concat works, but i want the dictionaries mported from an external txt file in my local disk drive. 
i tired: 
 f = open('data.txt', 'r')      
 x =[f]

but got error:

 ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (1, 1)

Comment: @Sam It's another question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) to load your data from the text file.

With contents of input file `file.txt`:

```
{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'}
{'a':'4','b':'5','c':'6'}
{'a':'7','b':'8','c':'9'}
{'a':'10','b':'11','c':'12'}
{'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}
```

You could use this script to load the data and input `file.csv`:

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    lst = [literal_eval(line) for line in f_in if line.strip()]

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

`file.csv` will become:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
x,y,z
```

Importing the file to LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: for the same code, am getting below error. anything am missing out?
---> writer.writerows(lst)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: @Sam You are trying to write tuples instead of dictionaries with DictWriter. `writerows()` function accept list/tuple of dictionaries, not list of lists.